# Read from "non existing" (In disk) Excel with Java POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a (third party) software that loads data dinamically to an Open Excel (Via Visual Basic, I believe, but I am not sure), this excel is not saved until it is complete.

On the other side, I have a Java GUI that must read data on real-time from that Excel and show it to the user.

Is there a way to do this using POI? I already have all the algorithms and GUI ready, but third party software just changed the way it works and I need to change this.

**TL:DR: I need to read from an excel that is currently open (Exists in RAM), but is still not saved into disk, is it possible?**

Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: Can't be done. You will have to look at other solutions such as saving the document or an excel plugin that pushed the data to the Java engine.

Comment: I don´t think that is an option. I only have control over my Java program, I can´t edit the System or the Excels of the customer (Assuming I would need to install an excel plugin in the customers PC). Does this mean they have to change the system or else this is imposible?

Comment: Change the third party tool to tell Excel to save the contents to a temporary file once the data has been loaded into it?

Comment: That would be nice. But Third Party tool means I do not own it. So I can´t change the code, I will tell them to do so though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with Apache POI for some time, I can confirm:

**This is impossible**.